# Problemas con el borde-radius y el borde dashed

Tags: css, css3

```
h1{
      border: 10px solid  blue ;
      border-style: dashed solid;
      border-color: blue #222;
      transition: all 1s;
    }
    
    h1:hover{
     
      border-radius: 20px;
      color: red;
    }
```

Mi problema es que al hacer un borde Radius a un elemento con el borde dashed las raya del borde no quedan bien puestas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay una forma de evitar esto osea obtener un elemento con el borde más circular pero con el borde dashed sin que ocurra esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

veo que al border-style le estas dando dos estilos diferentes, uno para el vertical (dashed) y otro  al horizontal (solid).
Con quedarte el border-style solo con el valor de dashed deberia funcionar.
Aun asi, al hacer hover el borde dashed tiene un efecto raro en la animacion.
Aca la modificacion: https://jsfiddle.net/n8rxb5u3/2/

```
h1{
  border: 10px solid  blue ;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: blue #222;
  transition: all 1s;
}

h1:hover{
 
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).